# kubernetes: using Petset in bare metal environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, kubernetes

I was trying to setup Cassandra cluster by kubernetes 1.3.4 new alpha feature - Petset. Following the yaml file posted here:
http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/07/thousand-instances-of-cassandra-using-kubernetes-pet-set.html

My kubernetes cluster is based on 1.3.4 on bare metal environment with 10 powerful physical machines. However, after I created the Petset, I can get nothing from kubectl get pv.

run kubectl get pvc, i get following:

NAME                      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
cass-volume-cassandra-0   Pending                                      4h
cass-volume-cassandra-1   Pending                                      4h
cass-volume-cassandra-2   Pending                                      4h

Reading the README here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b829d4d4ef68e64b9b7ae42b46877ee75bb2bfd9/examples/experimental/persistent-volume-provisioning/README.md

saying the persistent volume will be automatically created if the kubenetes is running on asw, gce or Cinder. Wondering any way I can create such persistent volume and pvc on bare metal environment?

Another question: as long as I run kubernetes cluster on a few EC2 machines in aws, above persistent volume from aws EBS will be automatically created with these clauses in yaml file? or I have to allocate EBS first?

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 380Gi
```

Answer (score 2):

petset using Dynamic volume provisioning, this means volumeClaimTemplates in the petset definition request for storage from kubernetes, if storage available pvc bound and pod(petset) is running! but for now kubernetes only support "Dynamic volume provisioning" in cloud provider like gce or aws.

if you use kubernetes in bare metal cluster, other way is using network storage like ceph or gluster that need setup network storage in your cluster.

if you want using bare metal hard disk, existen solution is using hostPath type of persistent volume.

Comment: arastu, actually i didn't find any document saying petset can use ceph or gluster network storage in bare metal cluster. Any sample or doc about provision such network volume for petset? Thanks a lot

Comment: @gordon-jiang for gluster see this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/e5f237a7ff6fae9ee10174890f0229fe91c5c477/examples/spark/spark-gluster/spark-worker-controller.yaml and for other search term in kubernetes repo in github or search in kubernetes.github.io repo

Answer (score 1):

By default, the host path provisioner is set to `false` in the `cluster/local-up-cluster.sh`. You can enable it by running `ENABLE_HOSTPATH_PROVISIONER=true cluster/local-up-cluster.sh`. This enables the provisioner and the PV gets created.

Comment: From this reference "A fourth provisioner is included for testing and development only. It creates HostPath volumes, which will never work outside of a single node cluster". Seems it only works for single node cluster. My cluster is composed of 10 physical machines.
Any idea?

Comment: Then you should be using NFS.